# Chrome extension: adding a keyboard shortcut with Alt with addEventListener('keypress')

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, keyboard-shortcuts

I am doing this [open source chrome extension](https://github.com/MagTun/Customizable-Google-Translate-Chrome-extension) and I would like to add a shortcut so that when the extension is open and I press `Alt+C`, then the content of a div is copied to my clipboard.

I am able to add shortcuts with a simple `addEventListener`:

```
var inputText = document.getElementById('textareaSource');
    inputText.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 99) {        
            // alert("You pressed C!");
        }
});
```

But apparently this way of adding shortcut doesn't allow shortcuts containing `Alt`. I tried this but I didn't get any alert:

```
if (e.altKey || e.ctrlKey || e.shiftKey)
    alert("you pressed one of the 'Alt', 'Ctrl', or 'Shift' keys")
}
```

I am also able to add shortcuts via `manifest`/`background.js` (following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37993631/3154274) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44514135/3154274)). This time, the `Alt+C` works but it can be triggered everywhere on Chrome and not only when my extension is opened.

Is there a way to get a middle ground: adding a shortcut containing `Alt` that is only triggered when my extension is opened?

Comment: `keypress` is for events that produce an unmodified letter or a digit so you need `keydown`, most likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `keypress` event won't fire when a modifier key has been pressed, additionally, now it is deprecated.

As it say [on the MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_event), you should consider using [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keydown_event) event instead, which supports the way you've tried.

`event.keyCode` is also deprecated, and `event.key` should be used instead.

So this code should work:

```js
var inputText = document.getElementById('textareaSource');
    inputText.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
        if (e.key == "c" && e.altKey) {        
            // alert("You pressed Alt + C!");
        }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. One last question: how to catch `Alt+Enter`? It doesn't work with `keydown`.

Comment: @MagTun I've noticed that `event.keyCode` is also deprecated, so I've replaced it...

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough: I tried this `if (e.key == 13 && e.altKey)` with a `keydown` to catch `Alt+Enter` but it doesn't work

Comment: `e.key` returns a string instead of a char code, so you should try e.key==='Enter'...

Comment: Sorry, I should have checked this one. Thanks a lot for your patience!