# TypeError: chrome.extension.getViews is not a function

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am writing chrome extension version 3 and inside background service worker I calls  `chrome.extension.getViews({ type: "popup" });` to know if popup is open. It works in version 2 but in version 3 gives TypeError: chrome.extension.getViews is not a function error

Comment: It doesn't work in ManifestV3 service worker and will never work because workers use a separate thread. You can use messaging instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a upcoming new api which should replace the existing v2 api

```
chrome.runtime.getContexts(
  filter: ContextFilter,
  callback?: function,
)
```

[docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-getContexts)

[blog post](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/extension-news-july-2023/#coming-soon-apis)

[proposal](https://github.com/w3c/webextensions/blob/main/proposals/runtime_get_contexts.md)