# How to close the popup of a Chrome extension from a service worker?

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to close the popup from a service worker using `chrome.extension.getViews`, but I get `TypeError: chrome.extension.getViews is not a function`. I learned from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67245672/typeerror-chrome-extension-getviews-is-not-a-function) that the API has changed in version 3 and that I should use `chrome.runtime.getContexts`. `getContexts` is also defined in the [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-getContexts), but when I try to use it in code TSlint gives me `Property  getContexts  does not exist on type  typeof runtime`. Is this a problem with Typescript or why else is it not allowing me to use it?

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "Node16",
    "moduleResolution": "Node16",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

getContexts was added in Chrome 116 (see the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/runtime/#method-getContexts)), so you need to use a different type definition package that is updated from the source code - the **official** [chrome-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-types).

However, there's a simpler method: send a message to the popup, so it closes itself.

// background script

```js
chrome.runtime.sendMessage('closePopup').catch(() => {});
```

// popup script

```js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(msg => {
  if (msg === 'closePopup') window.close();
});
```

Comment: Tried the message way, got response `Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by them.`

Comment: This code works with the `action` popup, which is what "popup" usually means in regards to chrome extension, so apparently your popup is something else. Please show how you create it.

Comment: How to add `chrome-types` to my extension project ? I installed them but how to tell typescript they are there ?

Comment: I don't know, but it sounds like a basic task for which there should be a simple solution. Try googling how to add type definitions to typescript.